# Rigid body dynamics: modelling a polygon bounce off ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, collision, rigid-body-dynamics, models

I'm currently making a physics simulator, but I'm having some trouble making a polygon bounce off the floor. 
I know that collisions are normally modeled as described below by ja72, but I did it somewhat differently.

**What I'm trying to do:** 
When the polygon touches (penetrates) the ground, I want to apply a linear impulse $\overrightarrow{P}$ at the contact point such that the energy $E'$ of the polygon after the bounce is some elasticity constant $\epsilon\in[0,1]$ times the energy $E$ of the polygon before the bounce.
$$E'=\epsilon E$$

**My calculations:** 
Consider a cartesian coordinate system where the floor is $y=0$. Then $\overrightarrow{P}(0,p)$ where we expect $p$ to be positive.
Define:

- $m$: the mass of the polygon
- $I$: the rotational inertia
- $\overrightarrow{v}$: the initial velocity
- $\overrightarrow{v'}$: the velocity after the collision
- $\overrightarrow{\omega}$: the initial rotational velocity (a vector parallel to the $z$-axis)
- $\overrightarrow{\omega'}$: the rotational velocity after the collision
- $\overrightarrow{r}$: a vector going from the polygon's center of mass to the contact point

Furthermore, for a vector $\overrightarrow{a}$, we denote its length by $|\overrightarrow{a}|$ and we can index it as $a[0]$ or $a[1]$ to get the $x$- and $y$-component (scalars, not vectors), respectively.

$m$, $I$, $\overrightarrow{v}$, $\overrightarrow{\omega}$ and $r$ are given, and we want to calculate the magnitude $p$ of the impulse $\overrightarrow{P}$.
Because $\overrightarrow{v'}=\overrightarrow{v}+\frac{\overrightarrow{P}}{m}$ and $\overrightarrow{\omega'} = \overrightarrow{\omega} + \frac{\overrightarrow{r}\times\overrightarrow{P}}{I}$, we can calculate:
$$\frac{1}{2}m\cdot\overrightarrow{v'}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\cdot\overrightarrow{\omega'}^2 = E' = \epsilon E = \epsilon\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}m\cdot\overrightarrow{v}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\cdot\overrightarrow{\omega}^2\right)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow m\cdot\left(\overrightarrow{v}+\frac{\overrightarrow{P}}{m}\right)^2 + I\cdot\left(\overrightarrow{\omega}+\frac{\overrightarrow{r}\times\overrightarrow{P}}{I}\right)^2 = \epsilon\cdot\left(m\cdot\overrightarrow{v}^2 + I\cdot\overrightarrow{\omega}^2\right)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow m\cdot\overrightarrow{v}^2 + 2\overrightarrow{v}\cdot\overrightarrow{P} + \frac{\overrightarrow{P}^2}{m} + I\cdot\overrightarrow{\omega}^2 + 2\overrightarrow{\omega}\cdot(\overrightarrow{r}\times\overrightarrow{P}) + \frac{(\overrightarrow{r}\times\overrightarrow{P})^2}{I} = \epsilon\cdot\left(m\cdot\overrightarrow{v}^2 + I\cdot\overrightarrow{\omega}^2\right)$$

And now, we can use the fact that $\overrightarrow{P}(0,p)$ to calculate the dot and cross products:
$$0 = (1-\epsilon)\cdot\left(m\cdot\overrightarrow{v}^2 + I\cdot\overrightarrow{\omega}^2\right) + 2p\cdot v[1] + \frac{p^2}{m} + 2p\cdot r[0]\cdot|\overrightarrow{\omega}| + \frac{(p\cdot r[0])^2}{I}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \left[\frac{1}{m}+\frac{r[0]^2}{I}\right]\cdot p^2 + \left[2v[1]+2r[0]\cdot|\overrightarrow{\omega}|\right]\cdot p + (1-\epsilon)\cdot\left[m\cdot\overrightarrow{v}^2 + I\cdot\overrightarrow{\omega}^2\right]$$

This is a quadratic equation in $p$.
If we set:

$A = \frac{1}{m}+\frac{r[0]^2}{I}$

$B = 2v[1]+2r[0]\cdot|\overrightarrow{\omega}|$

$C = (1-\epsilon)\cdot\left[m\cdot\overrightarrow{v}^2 + I\cdot\overrightarrow{\omega}^2\right]$

We can calculate the determinant $D = B^2-4AC$.

Now, it is clear that $p=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{D}}{2A}$.
Actually, $p=\frac{-B+\sqrt{D}}{2A}$, as $B$ must be negative to enforce a collision, and the sign of $v[1]$ must be reversed.

When I run this in a simulation, it looks very natural.
However, it always glitches when $D<0$.
I've tried to resolve this problem in countlessly many ways <sup>$(*)$</sup>, but it never worked out well.

Can anyone check whether my method and calculations are correct?
And if not, how can I model this collision instead?

Here is a snippet of my code (in Python):

```
class POLYGON:
    def bounce(self):
        #Checks whether the polygon touches the ground and makes it rebound if necessary

        low_nodes = []    #makes a list of the nodes with y<0
        for node in self.nodes:
            if node[1] <= 0:
                low_nodes.append(node)

        if len(low_nodes) >= 1:
            speed = self.speed
            self.translate([0, -2*lowest_node[1])    #lifts the lowest node above the ground

            for node in low_nodes:
                r = node - self.pos    #calculates r

                A = 1/self.mass + r[0]**2/self.rot_inertia
                B = 2*self.speed[1] + 2*self.rot_speed*r[0]
                C = (1-restituence_constant) * (self.mass*np.linalg.norm(self.speed)**2 + self.rot_inertia*self.rot_speed**2)
                D = B**2 - 4*A*C

                if D<0:
                    impulse = [0, -B/(2*A)]
                else:
                    impulse = [0, (-B-np.sqrt(D)) /(2*A) /len(low_nodes)]
                self.applyLinearImpulse(impulse, node)
```

<sup>$(*)$</sup> 
For example: 
using the absolute value of $D$ 
regarding $p$ as a complex number and applying the impulse $\overrightarrow{P}(\Im(p), \Re(p))$ 
setting $p=\frac{-B}{2A}$ if $D<0$ 
...

Comment: Usually, the bounce speed is reduced by the coefficient of restitution and not the energy,

Comment: Yes, I know.
However, I found my objects bouncing unnaturally when I applied the impulse P(0, -(1+e) * self.velocity[1] * self.mass), as no rotational characteristics are concerned.
I thought this would be a better way of modelling the collision, as the kinetic energy keeps decreasing.

Comment: So instead of the ratio of speeds, you specify the ratio of energy. But how is the contact direction enter into the calculation? If you have a contact that was largely tangential, it seems to me, your method would slow it down like it enters a bath of oil instead of bouncing off at a specific direction.

Comment: When r[0]^2/I is close to 0 (almost always), then A~=1/m. Let's say A=1/m.
Then p = (-B+sqrt(D)) / (2A) >= -v_tan[1] / (1/m) >= -m*v_tan[1], so the object bounces off.
The problem occurs when D<0 or when r[0]^2/I ís big (happens very rarely). I have not (yet) found a solution to this issue.

Comment: A couple of points here. First - a question like this would really benefit from a diagram. Second - can you attribute a physical meaning to the determinant? In what conditions can it go negative and what does that mean for the physics of the situation? Is it a numerical stability issue or even an actual physical impossibility? If D<0 and very small maybe you just ignore it?

Comment: How are you modeling the impulse?  And are you treating corner versus flat edge contact differently?  Also, are you looking at impulse due to Normal force alone or with traction between surfaces?  These differences will drive different end states.  Can your polygons be concave?  If so are you treating multiple contact points?  Or are you just treating the contact force direction as random.  I think you should add these points for completeness.

Comment: @JonasDeSchouwer, you have an incomplete sentence that bothers me.  You state "And now, we can use the fact that..." to evaluate cross products.  But you make no statement about P.  It disappears.  Please clarify.

Comment: @ggcg we use the fact that P is perpendicular to the ground to evaluate the cross products (with respect to the magnitude p).

Comment: @JonasDeSchouwer, thanks for the clarification.  That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

The physics of contact [can be found at many online resources](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/index.html), so I am just going to summarize below.

The impulse $\vec{P}$ needs to decomposed into the magnitude $p$ and the known contact normal direction $\vec{n}$, such that $\vec{P} = p\, \vec{n}$. The impulse <strike>magnitude</strike> is found from the law of collision that states that the relative velocity at the contact point and along the contact normal after the collision is a fraction of the relative impact velocity

$$ v_{\rm relative}' = -\epsilon \, v_{\rm impact} $$

mathematically the above is expressed as follows when an object impacts the ground (single body impact).

$$ \vec{n} \cdot (\vec{v}'+\vec{\omega}' \times \vec{r}) = -\epsilon \;\; \vec{n} \cdot ( \vec{v} + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}) $$

where $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{v}'$ are expressed at the center of mass before and after the impact, and the rest according to the author's post.

State the equations of motion & kinematics to get equation 8-18 from [the linked paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf) that gives the impact magnitude

> $$ p = \frac{ -(1+\epsilon)\; \vec{n}\cdot \vec{v} }{
>  \frac{1}{m} + \vec{n} \cdot \left( I^{-1} (\vec{r} \times \vec{n}) \right) \times \vec{r} }$$

The final velocity will be adjusted then accordingly

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \vec{P} & = p \,\vec{n} \\
  \vec{v}' & = \vec{v} + \tfrac{1}{m} \vec{P} \\
  \vec{\omega}' & = \vec{\omega} + I^{-1} \left( \vec{r} \times \vec{P} \right) \end{aligned} $$

---

I have also [linked an answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/249114/392) to a similar question in 2D.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had already found this formula, but without explanation. So I thought that v_rel was the relative velocity between (the centers of mass of) A and B, instead of the relative linear velocity of the contact points.

Comment: I'm not going to accept this answer (yet), though, as I would still like to know whether my method is sound and how to improve it.

Comment: @JonasDeSchouwer - thank you for pointing out the inconsistency in nomenclature in my post. I have corrected it to have $\vec{v}$ specified at the center of mass (per your post).

Comment: By the way, how can I handle an edge-ground collision?
When I use the code I have now (based on your formula) just to process the vertex-ground collisions, it doesn't work.
When I drop a square (+-100,+-100) on it's edge, the impulse is too small.
However, when I drop a 'truncated triangle' (+-10, 100); (+-100, -100), it does (because the edge is smaller and the vertices are (almost) under the center of mass)

Comment: @JonasDeSchouwer - I have seen the same effect where an object falling flat barely bounces, but when slightly rotated it bounces vigorously. I think the culprit is a succession of rapid contacts on alternating corners, each sapping some energy. Each contact counter-rotating the object, causing the next contact on the opposite corner. I don't have a good fix, but this can form the basis of a great new question to be posted in [Physics.SE]. Note that robust modeling of contacts is still a subject of ongoing research. There are still novel answers to be found there.

Comment: I've asked [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/174224/polygon-doesnt-bounce-in-edge-ground-collision) in [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) (instead of Physics). You might want to check it out.

Comment: @JonasDeSchouwer - Good idea.